# VB.NET wmpVideoPlayer .exe error: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am building a Windows Application via VB.NET, this windows application has to play videos and this works when I run my Application locally, but when I generate the .exe file and move the .exe file out of the bin folder and run my application I get this error when attempting to play a video:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'AxInterop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

I did notice when I generate the .exe via Build -> Build Solution the .exe file goes into a bin folder, also there is my video files, so I am assuming because my .exe file is not in the same location as my video files it why I am getting this error, Ideally I would love the .exe file to run without the video files not being there, but get added to the Application like Images are, is this possible?

I am setting the Path of the videos in wmpVideoPlayer properties via the URL parameter.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is related to the missing assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib', which is needed to work with the Windows Media Player control in your VB.NET application. This error typically occurs when the required assemblies are not deployed along with your executable file.

So in additon of moving the exe file you also need to move this file(and other dll files in the bin folder)